# Mocking some getters of a class and leaving all other methods the same with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

As the title describes I would like to mock 3 getters of my class for testing purposes as the variables are only available when the program is in operation and a connection is established.

Using JUnit5 my BeforeEach setup:

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    dataStore = new DataStore();
    when(dataStore.getSecurityPrincipal()).thenReturn("CREDENTIALS");
    when(dataStore.getSecurityCredentials()).thenReturn("CREDENTIALS");
    when(dataStore.getProviderUrl()).thenReturn("CREDENTIALS");
}
```

But I want all the other methods of this class to remain the same, I thought about doing something like `when(dataStore.getExample(anyString(), anyString())).thenCallRealMethod()` for each method but there are a lot of methods and that would mean a lot of extra lines of code. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use spy instead of mock, anything you don't spy would call the original method without you specifying it

Comment: Yes! Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for. This is going to be so useful for unit testing.